# What's the difference between 今日{きょう} and 本日{ほんじつ}?

Tags: definitions, synonyms, word-choice, keigo, time

I also see both in different examples.

As in :

> 今日は暑い。
>
> 本日はおめでとうございます。

Both are translated as "Today", but when and how should I use either one?

Can we say : 本日はあつい。 And 今日はおめでとうございます。?

Comment: 「本日はあつい」 sounds quite strange to me. In my mind, 本日 is a word used in formal situations, e.g. messages from a company to its customers – say, 「本日ご来店ありがとうございます」...

Comment: Yeah but I think we normally say 本日「は」、ご来店(誠に)ありがとうございます or 本日「の」ご来店、誠にありがとうございます.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

本日 is keigo. You will hear this on a train or airplane, or in a store. But you won't be saying it yourself, unless if you as a beginning student are put in the unlikely position of making an official announcement to someone.

今日 is what you would use in ordinary situations.

Comment: Oh, I see. But that means that actually both 今日はおめでとうございます and 本日はおめでとうございます work fine ?

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is misleading: 本日 is formal, but is not a keigo (unless you count all formal words as keigo).  The rest is good.

Comment: @BabyAzerty I'd say 本日はおめでとうございます rather than 今日はおめでとうございます. (because 本日 and ございます both sound formal but 今日 doesn't)

Comment: I happened upon this question, after my wife used it during a phone call when making a reservation. Her explanation was that, in addition to being more formal, it's also harder to mistake for another word (whereas 今日 could sound like other words). Probably relevant for phone conversations.

Answer (score 10):

Although 本日 will usually be too formal for most situations, there are many cases where you would use it over 今日 (with slightly different nuances).

Typically when referring to something tied to the day's date:

> 本日の魚 (in a restaurant)
>
> 本日の会議 (in a professional context)
>
> etc.